# JFormer: How to add confirm page with yes\no buttons

Tags: jquery, jformer

I need help. I'm new in JFormer and Javascripting issues. Could anyone give advice or show an example how to add a page which would be able to show a confirm message with yes&no buttons inside? I mean I have a simple form like here:

http://pastebin.com/rPggtdrM

And want that the page appeared after submit action with a message "Are you sure? and buttons Yes(go to executable script) and No (return to form page) "

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use Alertify.  It's very pretty and VERY easy to use:

http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

Comment: Actually, just noticed the jformer stuff.  Hmm.  Not sure whether you can use that.  But worth a check anyway

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Hope it works and tell me how it goes :)